# How to set condition where I get value from one table equal to other table Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables action list and priorities. Both tables share few similar attributes namely Category, and Subcategory. ActionList and Priorities have parent child relationship, with Priorities as the parent. There are several things that I want to do. 1. ActionList is semi-independent. 2. ActionList needs to get subcategory and Priorities from KP table. 3. When I do get the subcategory from AL table I want it to be "distinct" So for e.g. I input 4 different categories - Website, ChinaT, EastTiger, and BlueMountain with all of them get repeated twice for different priorities. I already insert distinct but failed. 4. When I click on Priorities dropdown I want it to get filter by subcategories. E.g In KP table Subcat Website has 2 priorites namely Provide Newsletter, and put on video. In ChinaT the priorities are Customer service, and Discussing next step, and on for the other two subcats

Cheers,

Andreas.

Comment: I have hard time following your thoughts, do you have any code sample that could be clearer?

Comment: @ForceMagic .OK, I'll try to be clearer. ActionList and Priorities have parent child relationship. With Priorities as the parent. There are several things that I want to do. 1. ActionList is semi independent. 2. ActionList need to get subcategory and Priorities from KP table. 3. When I do get the subcategory from AL table I want it to be "distinct" So for e.g I input 4 different categories - Website, ChinaT, EastTiger, and BlueMountain with all of them get repeated twice for different priorities. I already insert distinct but failed. 4. When I click on Priorities dropdown I want it to get ...

Comment: filter by subcategories. E.g In KP table Subcat Website has 2 priorites namely Provide Newsletter, and put on video. In ChinaT the priorities are Customer service, and Discussing next step, and on for the other two subcats. If it is not clear yet is there way to upload my file in stack or can I send it to your email?

Comment: You should edit your post to add those useful information :)

Answer (score -1):

Ι am working in database, the think i stop with is that, ex; company with many positions as manager wich he can get 4 courses ,  team leader wich he can get 3 courses, and regular employee get 2.
what i need to know if need to get messege when each positions reach the limite? as you know i have many team leader and employees.
thank you